# Google Play Games Services - Leaderboards, Can Only See Current User's Score

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-games, leaderboard

We have a game with Google Play Leaderboard support, and we can validate that scores are being sent to Google, updated, and being persisted, but only the current user can see their score. We know that all the scores are being stored because the Google Play console shows a correct tally of "Unique players who posted a score to a leaderboard".

The score the player sees is accurate and correct, but the player can only see their own score.

The Leaderboard is published and the users are in the right test segments.

Has anyone come across this in the past, and if so, can you please point us in the right direction? Google Support have not been able to assist as it is a development matter.

Comment: did you ever come to a conclusion on this? for my game "Unique players who posted a score to a leaderboard" is 1 but sometimes both me and testers have seen each other, just for a brief moment.. so the submissions must have gone through and then disappeared..